# Which version of Microsoft Office introduced the ability to edit and save to PDF files?

Tags: windows, microsoft-office

As of the latest several versions of the Microsoft Office suite, it now appears to be possible to interact with PDF files - Word documents can now be saved as a PDF, and PDF files can now be opened and edited directly from within Microsoft Word. Which versions of Office initially introduced this functionality?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Which versions of Office initially introduced this functionality?

Exporting PDFs was introduced in Office 2007 Service Pack 2:

> Initially, Microsoft promised to support exporting to Portable Document Format (PDF) in Office 2007. However, due to legal objections from Adobe Systems, Office 2007 originally did not offer PDF support out of the box, but rather as a separate free download. However, **starting with Service Pack 2, Office allows users to natively export PDF files**.

Source [Microsoft Office 2007 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2007#PDF)

Full read, write and edit support was added in Office 2013:

> Microsoft Office 2013 includes updated support for ISO/IEC 29500, the International Standard version of Office Open XML (OOXML) file
>   format: in particular it supports saving in the "Strict" profile of
>   ISO/IEC 29500 (Office Open XML Strict). It also supports OASIS
>   version 1.2 of ISO/IEC 26300:2006, Open Document Format, which
>   Office 2013 can read and write. Additionally, **Office 2013 provides
>   full read, write, and edit support for ISO 32000 (PDF).**
>
> ...
>
> Other features of Office 2013 include:
>
> - PDF Import feature in Microsoft Word

Source [Microsoft Office 2013 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_2013#New_features)

Comment: +1 because your answer is the only one that actually include the import feature.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia says for Microsoft Office, section
[Desktop applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office#Desktop_applications):

> Support for Portable Document Format (PDF) and OpenDocument (ODF) was first introduced in Word for Windows with Service Pack 2 for Word 2007.

Answer (score 0):

> Which versions of Office initially introduced this functionality?

Based on the [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-or-make-changes-to-a-pdf-file-5a316914-6901-470a-9dcd-fe87a51ceed4) to edit PDFs within Office.  This feature requires Office 2010 or newer.

However, Office 2007 did indeed have this feature, but required you to install the [2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=4d951911-3e7e-4ae6-b059-a2e79ed87041&DisplayLang=en&WT.mc_id=-blog-scottha) add-on in order to save a document as a PDF.  While I have linked to this add-on, the file is not longer accessible, it's simply there for posterity.  Office 2007 Service Pack 2 added the ability to save a document as a PDF natively.

> Office 365, Office 2019, Office 2016, Office 2013, Office 2010

Sources:

- [Edit or make changes to a PDF file](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/edit-or-make-changes-to-a-pdf-file-5a316914-6901-470a-9dcd-fe87a51ceed4)
- [Save or convert to PDF or XPS in Project desktop](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/save-or-convert-to-pdf-or-xps-in-project-desktop-d85416c5-7d77-4fd6-a216-6f4bf7c7c110)
- [2007 Microsoft Office Add-in: Microsoft Save as PDF or XPS](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/2007MicrosoftOfficeAddinMicrosoftSaveAsPDFOrXPS.aspx)
- [Microsoft Expands List of Formats Supported in Microsoft Office](https://news.microsoft.com/2008/05/21/microsoft-expands-list-of-formats-supported-in-microsoft-office/)

Comment: Exporting PDFs was introduced in Office 2007 Service Pack 2

Comment: The quoted listed of Office products is consolidated by major versions, the list of Office products also includes various other Office products (Viso, Project, Publisher, Access) for those versions, a complete list seem excessive.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tadd/2009/04/15/microsoft-update-product-team-blog-service-pack-2-for-2007-microsoft-office-system-due-april-28th/ "Save As PDF/XPS support has been built into the SP2 of these Office applications. Users no longer have to download the add-in separately."

Comment: https://news.microsoft.com/2008/05/21/microsoft-expands-list-of-formats-supported-in-microsoft-office/ "With the release of Microsoft Office 2007 Service Pack 2 (SP2) scheduled for the first half of 2009, the list will grow to include support for XML Paper Specification (XPS), Portable Document Format (PDF) 1.5, PDF/A and Open Document Format (ODF) v1.1. "